# How to compare 2 button title using index or tag value

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton

Here my application i having set of button 12 buttons,button titles are hidden by default.Button titles are shown when it is clikced ,

```
-(IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    int index = button.tag;
    [self showing:index]; //now, this method accepts a parameter.
}

-(void)showing:(NSInteger)index
{
UIButton* btn = nil;
index = index - 1;
NSArray* subViewArray = [self.view subviews];

NSInteger i = 0;

for (UIView *view in subViewArray)
{
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
    {
        btn = (UIButton*) view;
        if(btn.tag >= 1 && btn.tag <= 16)
        {
            NSString* text;
            UIButton *prevButton = (UIButton*) [self.view viewWithTag:previousButtonTag];
            if (i == index) {

                if ([btn.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:prevButton.titleLabel.text])
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    text=@"";
                }
            text = [texts objectAtIndex:i]; //put the array that you are using
        }
        else {
            text = @"";
        }

        i++;

        [btn setTitle:text forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }// end of IF
} //end of FOR

}
```

1.I want to compare two button title values to check whether it is equal or not.Im facing the problem ,

2.Only press button title only visible,when i click other button previous title is hided,I want to enable two button title on click and wen it is wrong it should be hided.Please suggest me the How to solve this issue,Please do the needfully

Comment: which button with you want to compare clicked button title??

Comment: @ParasJoshi with previously clicked button

Comment: see the code, i just add some code and just modify, try with some changes in code.. i hope you'll got some idea from it.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your `showing` like:

```
-(void) showing:(NSInteger)index
{
  UIButton *btn = (UIButton*) [self.view viewWithTag:index];
  NSString *text = [self.textArray objectAtIndex:index]; //put the array that you are using
  [btn setTitle:text forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  if (self.previousButtonTag != -1)
  {
     UIButton *prevButton = (UIButton*) [self.view viewWithTag:previousButtonTag];
     if ([btn.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:prevButton.titleLabel.text])
     {
     }
     else
     {
       //hide the prevButton
       [prevButton setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     }
   }
  self.previousButtonTag = index; //make a class variable
}
```

`IButton *btn = (UIButton*) [self.view viewWithTag:index];` will give you the currently clicked button. `UIButton *prevButton = (UIButton*) [self.view viewWithTag:previousButtonTag];` give you the previously clicked button. As per your need you can check the titles in the if condition, if they are equal do your stuff there, if not equal then hiding the previous button title.

You need to initialize the previous button tag to -1 in your `viewDidLoad`

Comment: problem with previousButtonTag

Comment: what is the issue with previousButtonTag ?

Comment: where should we want to intitalise the previousButtonTag value

Comment: previousButtonTag is type of int and if(btn.title==prevButton.title) is that is right to check

Comment: i want to show the title on click yaar,but its showing when it launching itself

Comment: That's another question :( you need to set all title's to @"" in the `viewDidLoad` if your buttons are located in the xib, set title to blank

Comment: i updated the code in my question .Please go through and tell me what change should in made

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19192/discussion-between-fasil-moham-and-midhun-mp)

Answer (score 0):

Do some changes with this code , i just try to understand your requirement and add logic for display title of previous button and current button title..

```
    -(void) showing:(NSInteger)index
    {
        UIButton* btn = nil;
        index = index - 1; 
        NSArray* subViewArray = [self.view subviews];
        NSInteger i = 0;

        UIButton *btnCurTemp = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:index];


        for (UIView *view in subViewArray) 
        {
            if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) 
            {
                btn = (UIButton*) view;
                NSString* text;
                if (i == index) {
                    text = [self.textArray objectAtIndex:i]; //put the array that you are using
                    [btnCurTemp setTitle:text forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                    UIButton *btnPrevTemp = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:self.prevButtonTag];

                  if ([btnCurTemp.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:btnPrevTemp.titleLabel.text]) {
                     /// visible your both button title..
                 }
                 else {
                     //// hide button title..
                 }
                    self.previousButtonTag = i; //make a class variable

                }else {
                    text = @"";
                }
                i++;

            }
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply compare the array strings values using the button tags as the index -

```
NSString * firstString = [self.textArray objectAtIndex:btn.tag];
NSString * secondString = [self.textArray objectAtIndex:prevButton.tag];
if([firstString isEquleToString:secondString]){

}else{

}
```